# How to use FPC to compile Free Pascal code to *.apk files?

Tags: android, apk, lazarus, freepascal

There is an app out there called "PascalGUI" [(Link to google play store)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidpascal&hl=de) which can compile the code into APK files.

I looked through the web and emailed the developer but i cant find any way how i could do the same thing. I think he uses the official fpc sources and just passes the code but im not sure.

Is there any documentary or someone who knows how this could have been made?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, FPC is [cross platform](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Setup_Cross_Compile_For_ARM), so it can target many processor architectures. Creating Android Application using FPC can be done through [Android NDK](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Android), and it can also be done using Android SDK.

[Michael Van Canneyt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2781208/michael-van-canneyt) wrote in [his page](https://www.freepascal.org/~michael/articles/android1/android1.pdf) about creating Android using FPC and Android SDK.
I'm not sure if that App uses same approach, but this seems to be very similar.

**Update (12/2017):**
The easy recommend way to build Android applications (APK) using Lazarus -as for now- can be done using [Laz4Android](https://sourceforge.net/projects/laz4android/) and "[Lazarus Android Module Wizard](https://github.com/jmpessoa/lazandroidmodulewizard)".

Hope this help.

Comment: There are android 2 and android 3 documents also. https://www.freepascal.org/~michael/articles/